# Most efficient way to get size of an AppEngine Datastore query

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

What is the most efficient way to get the size of an AppEngine Datastore query?

Say I have a query with filters such that the number of entities retrieved would be N. Is it possible to get the value of N without doing the full datastore retrieval?

The most efficient way I have found is to use a "keys only" query, thus:

```
Query q = new Query("MyKind").setKeysOnly();
q.setFilter(someFilter);
PreparedQuery pq = datastore.prepare(q);
long N = pq.asList().size();
```

Is there a better way?  If I only want to know if the size N exceeds a certain value, is there a more efficient way?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why not use countEntities?  https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/datastore/PreparedQuery#countEntities(com.google.appengine.api.datastore.FetchOptions)

You could also track the count yourself in a sharded counter.  Another thought is if you only need an estimate try an eventually consistent query which should be faster.

Comment: D'oh! How could I miss that? Even so, do we expect that to be less costly from a datastore quota point of view, and from a latency point of view?

Comment: you'd have to test to be sure, but my guess is they would be pretty close.  you would be returning slightly less info (a number instead of a list of keys) but it should be close.  If you really need low latency counts of items you should research a sharded counter.

Comment: countEntities has a limit of 1000